# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found

Tags: php, laravel

i am installing laravel for the first time everything seemed perfect until i enter the command 'php artisan serve'. its showing

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /home/poojitha/.composer/vendor/bin/blog/bootstrap/app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /home/poojitha/.composer/vendor/bin/blog/artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/poojitha/.composer/vendor/bin/blog/bootstrap/app.php on line 14
```

i tried every command like

`composer dump-autoload`

```
`composer update --no-scripts`

`composer dump-autoload`

`composer install --no-scripts`
```

nothing is working

Comment: Did you delete your vendor folder and composer.lock before trying `composer install --no-scripts`?

Comment: yes i did still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message shows you have a problem with composer autoloading. Try the following steps;

1. Make sure you have deleted the `vendor` folder and `composer.lock` file
2. Run `composer install`

Comment: it's showing ```No lock file found. Updating dependencies instead of installing from lock file. Use composer update over composer install if you do not have a lock file.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies```
and its updating some files but still its not working

Comment: i jst realized thar i am using old version of php and all the downloaded extensions are for the latest version. i updated php and its working. thank you